# Cannot check out code using TortoiseCVS1.12.3 in Win7

Tags: tortoisecvs

I am trying to check out source code from following URL using TortoiseCVS1.12.3 in Win7:
:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/webtools

But error appears:
In C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Local\Temp\TortoiseCVS make new module 
temp\: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\cvs.exe" -q -d 
:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/webtools import -m
XMLEditor tcvs-vendor tcvs-release
CVSROOT=:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/webtools

Empty password used - try 'cvs login' with a real password
cvs [server aborted]: "import" requires write access to the repository

Error, CVS operation failed

Do you know why the error happens?